# How to determine a operator norm?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

How to solve following:

In Hilbert space $W_2^1=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}|f\in AC[0,1], f'\in L^2[0,1]\}$ with scalar product $(f,g)=\int_0^1 f\overline{g}dx+\int_0^1 f'\overline{g'}dx$ is given function $F:W_2^1\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $F(f)=f(0)$.

Prove that F is bounded linear functional and find function $\phi$ with property $F(f)=(f,\phi)$. Determine $\|F\|$.

Linearity is easy to prove, but I couldn't determine what is function $\phi$. I assume that $\|F\|$ is easy to calculate, if we know $\phi$- this could probably be done by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I'm having problem to determine $\phi$.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi$ is say smooth then
$$\int_0^1\phi'f'\,dx=\phi'(1)f(1)-\phi'(0)f(0)-\int_0^1\phi''f\,dx.$$
As a result, if $\phi$ satisfies $\phi''=\phi$ then
$$(f,\phi)=\phi'(1)f(1)-\phi'(0)f(0).$$
So we want $\phi'(1)=0$ and $\phi'(0)=-1$. So $\phi(x)=a\exp(x)+b\exp(-x)$, $ae-be^{-1}=0$, $a-b=-1$,
which gives (I hope)
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{e^2-1}e^x+\frac{e^2}{e^2-1}e^{-x}.$$
The norm of the linear form is then $\sqrt{\phi,\phi}$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be $\int_0^1$?

Comment: I got solution $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{e^2-1} e^x+\frac{e^2}{e^2-1} e^{-x}$, under conditions $\phi''=\phi$, $\phi'(0)=-1$, $\phi'(1)=0$. Is that correct?

Comment: @alans I hope it's better now

Comment: I saw your post. Thanks.